# XML::Twig warning messages

Tags: perl, xml-twig

When i Iam nstalling the up to date version of XML::Twig

```
 Installed: 3.44
 CPAN:      3.44  up to date
 Michel Rodriguez (MIROD)
 xmltwig@gmail.com
```

I get this warning message when running perldoc XML::Twig

```
Wide character in print at C:/strawberry-perl/perl/lib/Pod
/Text.pm line 286.
```

Could someone help how i can fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is related to utf8 support. The data you provided is in utf8 while for some reason your XML::Twig is not expecting it to be as such.

Is this warning affecting you in any way? if so what is it causing?

Comment: I just installing the up to date version of XML::Twig do you know what is the reason this version can't handle UTF8 data ?

Comment: It is usually you not handling utf8 in a proper way, not the module. For example if you are not reading the data in a way that reads the data in utf8, it would fail

Comment: The long answer is read http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html specifically make sure ``utf8::is_utf8`` returns true on your data

Comment: Im not handling utf8 i just installed the module and only run perldoc XML::Twig its not relevant to my code if i handle utf8 or not

Comment: So XML::Twig is not relevant to your program? so why do you care about this warning?

Comment: Because when I installed previous version on another station i didn't get this warning i wonder if i am missing some recommended module or have a problem with the installtion

Comment: Open a bug in the package handler and see his reaction. In any case, the error is from Pod::Text and not XML::Twig

Comment: Ok thansk for your help